# Find the value of the sum of only 3 digit numbers such that dividing by it leaves REM = 11?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I had asked a Q similar to this.

[Find the value of this 3 digit number such that dividing by it leaves REM = 11](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4061208/878401)

But I want to know also if instead we take sum of all those numbers. Is there a way to solve this too in a similar way to that Q?

The problem happening is how to put limits in the sum such that the numbers are in between 100 and 999.

Comment: If you want to find the sum of all 3-digit numbers that gives remainder 11 upon dividing by 13, you should first note that these numbers form an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up all the $3$-digit numbers that give remainder $11$ upon dividing by $13$.

Note that they are of the form of $13k+11$.

$$100 \le 13k+11 \le 999$$

$$89 \le 13k \le 988$$

$$\lceil \frac{89}{13}\rceil  \le k \le \lfloor\frac{988}{13} \rfloor$$

$$7 \le k \le 76$$

I will leave the task of evaluating

$$\sum_{k=7}^{76}(13k+11)$$

as an exercise to you.